# nginx proxy_pass to flask works while /static fail to find jquery

Tags: nginx, redirect, proxypass

I'm a noob an nginx (and apache and php ...)

I've this flask app that works fine from:

`http://127.0.0.1:5000`
and also externally from
`http://myhost.com:5000`

I would like to use that from
`myhost.com/rest_1`
to make room to others rest, like myhost.com/rest_2 .. 3 and so on.
The app resides in
`/opt/rest_1`
and uses some resources from it's /static folder like css and jquery.

I've this
`/etc/nginx/sites-available/rest_1.conf`

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name myhost.com;
   server_name_in_redirect off;

   location /rest_1 {
            rewrite ^/rest_1(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
   }}
```

and it's link to sites-enabled.
nginx restart and reload with no errors.
Other configurations are default from installation.

When i try to connect to

`myhost.com/rest_1`

I can see an incomplete page partially working, looking at nginx log:
`/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

`*8 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/w3.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: myhost.com, request: "GET /static/w3.css HTTP/1.1", host: "myhost.com", referrer: "http://myhost.com/rest_1"`

So, it is clear to me that '/usr/share/nginx/html/' is got from elsewhere... and should also have a proper name that piece of folder (I'm a noob!!)

How to tell to the engine to redirect to the correct path on
`/opt/rest_1`
to get back all /static functionalities ?

OS: ubuntu server 16.04
nginx: 1.10.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cause you don´t set one location resource for your static content. Your app is referencing an CSS from de root folder and not from rest_1.

Your CSS Call was http://myhost.com/STATIC, so it not match in the location that you set and try inside the default.

So you can solve it in your app or you can set it in your nginx as below:

```
   location /static {
       root /opt/rest_1;
   }
```